# At least one checkbox validation AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, validation, checkbox

I'm trying to do a validation that validate an input `checkbox` when at least 1 option has been checked.

I followed an example found that require a `controller` but I would like have it **without** use a controller maybe a directive for that. How can i achieve that?

This example use a controller:

**Html**

```
<input
    type="checkbox"
    value="{{val.id}}"
    ng-model="formData.selectedFruits[val.id]"
    ng-required="!someSelected(formData.selectedFruits)"
>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.someSelected = function (object) {
  return Object.keys(object).some(function (key) {
    return object[key];
  });
}
```

Comment: So you want to constantly be validating if at least one is checked? Or only on a submit?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/007design/N3w8Z/   check this Dude  Good Luck